# How to fix the layout issue of chosen-select styles in bootstrap?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, css, jquery-chosen

I am trying to apply a style by using bootstrap css but every time  i am being un-successful .

What i am trying to do is :

```
    <link href="~/Theme/css/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Theme/Bootstrap37/css/chosen-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

     <section id="contact-page" class="EditMode" style="display:none;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="status alert alert-success" style="display: none"></div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                    <h5>&nbsp;&nbsp;Change your information</h5>
                    <form id="" class="" name="c_signup" method="post" action='@Url.Action("CSignUp","Profile", new { area="CPortal"})'
                          enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return validation(this)">

<div class="col-xs-6">
                        <div class="form-group">

  <label>Speciality</label>                         
                            <div >
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedSpecialityTest)
                                    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedSpecialityIds,
                                    new MultiSelectList(Model.Specialities, "OID", "SpecialityDesc"),
                                    new { @class = "chosen-select form-control", @required = "required" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>






   jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        $(".chosen-select").chosen({ no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!" });
});
```

Now when i see the view then chosen-select dropdown is not displaying instead just a tiny line.

See the complete working same at here:

https://codepen.io/maifs/pen/VWMwWw

Comment: Maybe because of this on the section tag `style="display:none;"`

Comment: No i have two sections on one page and i show just one section at a time .

Comment: function enableEdit() {
        $('.EditMode').show();
        $('.ViewMode').hide();
    }

Comment: Post a working code snippet so we can see what is going on

Comment: ok i upload at somewhere then i share it

Comment: LGSon, please look at this. I have uploaded the code

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AitLVJhHEke3go4LOrKf9zGtZbKTLw

Comment: No, I don't want to download and parse your code. Post a working code snippet here at SO, preferable in a Stack snippet though fiddle and codepen is other options

Comment: LGSon. I don't know how to upload my complete sample at these sites. These sites have limited features and i am afraid may be razor is not supported there

Comment: You should **not** upload the _complete_ code, just smallest possible to reproduce the output. Simply view the source when it has rendered, and then copy the markup together with the relevant CSS is enough

Comment: good idea LGSon but there are plugins Jquery, Bootstrap and Chosen select and their css files. How can i upload there ?

Comment: Follow this guide: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: LGSon thank you for helping . I tired to upload in this post but it is still giving  me errors. as $ is undefined. I uploaded the css and js plugins at drop box and files can be accessed. Moreover i have uploaded the source at codepen 
https://codepen.io/maifs/pen/VWMwWw

Comment: Dropbox does not provide cdn hosting services and therefore resources hosted there won't work when linked in a webpage/snippet. That's because `dropbox` says: I don't know what's inside this file, I don't trust it, While `cdnjs` says: this script is what it should be. I checked it. You can run it safely. So search for and use the links to the resources you use from [cdnjs.com](https://cdnjs.com/) and you'll be able to create a working fiddle anywhere you try to do it. If you don't use properly hosted resources, you won't be able to make it work. Not here, not on jsFiddle, not on codepen.

Comment: thank you andrei but stack overflow is not allowing me to enter more than body of 30000 and my length is 95000.  so i added up here.
https://codepen.io/maifs/pen/VWMwWw